# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" missing

Tags: javascript, request, cors, fetch-api

I am trying to build a webapp by retrieving information from a friend's API.
Using javascript, I made a code which, at least for Google documents, worked perfectly.
However, I now encounter this error:
`header CORS “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” missing`

There is the code:
`await fetch(url, { method: 'GET', mode: corse, cache: "no-cache", redirect: "follow", referrerPolicy: "no-referrer", credentials: "same-origin", });`

Is there any way to solve this problem?
I cannot attach the url because it is private, I apologize.

N.B: On the same API, using python and request without any header or anything else, I get the result, so I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i) before asking.

Comment: This is something your friend has to fix on their end. _"On the same API, using python and request without any header or anything else, I get the result, so I don't really understand what the problem is."_ - that's a completely different context, in which CORS restrictions do not apply to begin with.